# Remove subview when selecting it

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Here I add a subview to my superView by clicking on the superView:

```
@IBAction func tapRecognizerAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = sender.location(in: self.view)
    addNew(x: location.x, y: location.y)
}

func addNew(x : CGFloat, y : CGFloat){
    let testView: CustomView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 50, height: 50)) 
    testView.backgroundColor = .blue
    testView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(testView)

    let aSelector : Selector = #selector(PlanViewController.removeSubview)
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: aSelector)
    testView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func removeSubview(){

}
```

How can I remove a specific subview when I touch it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the tapped view in this way

```
func addNew(x : CGFloat, y : CGFloat){
    let testView: CustomView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 50, height: 50)) 
    testView.backgroundColor = .blue
    testView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(testView)

    let aSelector : Selector = #selector(PlanViewController.removeSubview(tapGestureRecognizer:))
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: aSelector)
    testView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

Then retrieve the tapped view in handler, and then remove it from super view

```
func removeSubview(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let tappedView = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! CustomView
    tappedView.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about you hold a reference to the view outside the function?

```
let testView: CustomView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 50, height: 50)) 
func addNew(x : CGFloat, y : CGFloat){

    testView.backgroundColor = .blue
    testView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(testView)

    let aSelector : Selector = #selector(PlanViewController.removeSubview)
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: aSelector)
    testView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
func removeSubview(){
    testView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```